# Command line syntax in Perforce

Tags: command-line, perforce, administration, owner, perforce-stream

One of our admins, the admin that happens to have created all of our release streams in Perforce happens to be out of town.  (We have just started on the tool) To help lock down our content we have both of the following items selected on our release streams: 
- Locked (only the stream owner can edit stream settings)
- Submitting files to the stream restricted to stream owner

Essentially we give people access as needed.  So that need came up today and we are unable to remove the settings above on the release stream even though we are Super Users/Admins.  I am not familiar at all with the command line syntax for Perforce commands but I would think something along the lines of

p4 stream -f //depot/stream_name owner=newuser

I realize my syntax is way off, if anyone has advice or can point in the direction of documentation that actually explain how to format commands that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the quick help that I often end up using:

```
p4 help - gets you general command syntax
p4 help commands - lists the commands
p4 help <command name> - provides detailed help for a specific command
```

Here is the online docs for "[p4 stream](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/stream.html)".  The dash F (-f) options looks like what you need. The online docs have nice examples at the very bottom of the CLI web pages that get you the general syntax and parameters you need.

```
p4 stream -t development -P main //projectX/bruno-dev
```

Here is the online docs for how to [manage stream tasks](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/streams_task.html) if that is what you needed as well. I remember managing that stuff was interesting.

It's been a few years since I did anything major in Perforce but those are what I remember.

Comment: it turns out the answer ended up being <p4 streams -f //depot/stream> this brings up the txt file context and I could change it...still not understanding why I had to use -f since I should have had access to update the stream via the permissions that had been set up, but I have that question into support.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
p4 stream -o -v //YourStream/Stream > spec.txt
```

then modify spec.txt (make a backup)

(-f for admins)

```
p4 stream -i -f < spec.txt
```